# How do i implement a semantic checker for given language

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, bison, semantics, lex

```
for(var x in z) {
 a = x + 1 + 2;
 foo();
 }
 function bar() {}
 for(t in []){
 function hello(a) {
 a = t + 'hello' + 'world';
 }
 bar();
 hello();
 }
 hello();
 function hello() {}
 15 * 30;
 1 + 2 + 3;
 a = 3 - 2 - 1;
 a + 10;
```

Lets say that we have a semantic rule which is when a function is called, the function shall be declared before in current scope or in the parent scope.

So since foo(); is not declared in above program(line 3 ) we need to print an error message.

For line 13 hello() is no declared so we need to print an error message.

We have bison/flex implementation however attribute grammer implementation is missing.

Parser:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h> 
void yyerror(const char * msg){
        printf("%s\n",msg);
}
%} 
%token tFOR tIN tSEMICOLON tLPAR tLBRKT tLT tSTAR tPLUS tPERCENT tINT tREAL tSTRING tWHILE tVAR tCOMMA tRPAR tRBRKT tRBRACE tGT tEQ tMINUS tNOT tIDENT tIF tCOLON tLBRACE tELSE tEQCHECK tFUNCTION
%left tMINUS tPLUS
%left tSTAR
%left tPERCENT
%left tLT tGT tEQCHECK
%left tNOT

%%
prog: statementList
;

statementList: statementList statement
             | statementList tSEMICOLON
             |
;

statement: assign
         | if
         | expr
         | while
         | for
         | functionCall
         | functionDeclaration
;

assign: tIDENT tEQ expr
      | tVAR tIDENT tEQ expr
;

if: ifPart elsePart
;

ifPart: tIF tLPAR expr tRPAR statementBlock
;

elsePart: tELSE statementBlock 
        | 
;

while: tWHILE tLPAR expr tRPAR statementBlock
;

for: tFOR tLPAR tIDENT tIN expr tRPAR statementBlock
   | tFOR tLPAR tVAR tIDENT tIN expr tRPAR statementBlock
;

functionDeclaration: tFUNCTION tIDENT tLPAR exprList tRPAR statementBlock
                   | tFUNCTION tIDENT tLPAR tRPAR statementBlock
;

statementBlock: tLBRACE statementList tRBRACE
;

functionCall: tIDENT tLPAR exprList tRPAR
            | tIDENT tLPAR tRPAR
;

expr: tIDENT
    | tREAL
    | tINT
    | tSTRING
    | tLBRKT tRBRKT
    | tLBRKT exprList tRBRKT
    | tLBRACE tRBRACE 
    | tLBRACE propertyList tRBRACE
    | tNOT expr
    | expr tPLUS expr
    | expr tMINUS expr
    | expr tSTAR expr
    | expr tEQCHECK expr
    | expr tLT expr
    | expr tGT expr
;

exprList: expr
        | exprList tCOMMA expr
;

propertyList: tIDENT tCOLON expr
            | propertyList tCOMMA tIDENT tCOLON expr
;

%%
int main() {
  return yyparse();
}
```

Scanner:

```
%{
#include "parser.tab.h"
%}
%%
in      return tIN;
function      return tFUNCTION;
for      return tFOR;
while    return tWHILE;
var      return tVAR;
";"      return tSEMICOLON;
"("      return tLPAR;
")"      return tRPAR;
"["      return tLBRKT;
"]"      return tRBRKT;
"<"      return tLT;
">"      return tGT;
"*"      return tSTAR;
"+"      return tPLUS;
"%"      return tPERCENT;
","      return tCOMMA;
"{"      return tRBRACE;
"}"      return tLBRACE;
"=="      return tEQCHECK;
"="      return tEQ;
"-"      return tMINUS;
"!"      return tNOT;
"-"?[0-9]+  return tINT;
("-"[0-9]+"."[0-9]+)|([0-9]*"."[0-9]+)   return tREAL;
('[^']*')|(["][^"]*["]) return tSTRING;
[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*  return tIDENT;
[ \t\n] 
.      return yytext[0];
%%
```

Comment: It is not clear if it is a general question or specific to your usage of bison/flex? If the former it is an extremely broad question. Perhaps narrowing down to specific would help.

Comment: >> "We have bison/flex implementation however attribute grammer implementation is missing."  Yep.  Implement one of those to do your semantic check.

Answer (score 0):

In the following grammar `tIDENT` and `tFUNCTION` are tokens.`Foo()` is a token.
You must keep a

> Symbol Table

in order to store `tIDENT` or `tFUNCTION` tokens.To check if  `foo`  has been declared before, you must traverse the symbol table and look if it is already inside.You must do this with variables also.

For example :

```
assign: tFUNCTION   {   
                        SYMBOL *s= NULL
                        if((s=symlook_function($1,depth,yylineno,param_count,symbol_list)) == NULL ){
                            strcat(errstr, "Found a function which is not decalared");
                            yyerror(errstr);
                        }
                }
```

You will have to implement your own Symbol Table and its functions such adding and searching in it in C language.Here `symlook` search inside the symbol table and if it doesn't find the token `tFUNCTION` `($1)` inside will produce an error message.You must also include different grammars inside.One when a function or veriable is `declaring` for the first time and one when you find it in `an expression.`
Check this C Yacc grammar.These are the production for C language: 
https://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ANSI-C-grammar-y.html

see this:

```
external_declaration
    : function_definition
    | declaration
```

When the production is `function_definition` ,the token `foo` enters inside the symbol table for the first time.If however you find again `foo` in a different production then you will have to search the symbol table and return `error` if it is missing.